# How to compare a column from table 1 to another column in table 2?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am quite new to SQLITE3 as well as python. I a complete beginner in SQLite. I don't understand much. I am right now learning as a go for my project.I am working on a project where I have one database with about 20 tables inside of it. One table is for user input and the other tables are pre-loaded with values. How can I compare and match which values that are in the pre-loaded table with the user table??  For example:

```
Users Table: 
Barcode:      Item: 
1234          milk
4321          cheese
5678          butter
8765          water
9876          sugar

Pre-Loaded Table: 
Barcode:       Availability:
1234               1
5678               1
9876               1
1111               1
```

Now, I want to be able to compare each row in the Pre-Loaded Table to each row in the Users Table. They both have the Barcode column in common to be able to compare. As a result, during the query process, it should check each row: 
1234 - milk - 1 (those columns are equal ) 
5678 - butter - 1 ( those columns are equal) 
9876 - sugar - 1 (those columns are equal) 
1100 - - 1 ( this barcode does not exist in the Users Table)

so when a Barcode, in this case, 1100 doesn't exist in the Users Table, the code should print: You don't have all the items for the Pre-Loaded Table. How can I get the code to this?

so far I have this: This code does work by the way.

```
import sqlite3 as sq



connect = sq.connect('Food_Data.db')
con = connect.cursor()

sql = ("SELECT Users_Food.Barcode, Users_Food.Item, Recipe1.Ham_Swiss_Omelet FROM Users_Food INNER JOIN Recipe1 ON Users_Food.Barcode = Recipe1.Barcode WHERE Recipe1.Ham_Swiss_Omelet = '1'")
con.execute(sql)
data = con.fetchall()
print("You can make: Ham Swiss Omelet")
formatted_row = '{:<10} {:<9} {:>9} '
print(formatted_row.format("Barcode", "Ingredients", "Availability"))
for row in data:
    print(formatted_row.format(*row))
    #print (row[:])
    #connect.commit()
```

It prints:

```
You can make: Ham Swiss Omelet
Barcode    Ingredients Availability 
9130849874 butter            1 
2870896881 eggs              1 
5501066727 water             1 
1765023029 salt              1 
9118188735 pepper            1 
4087256674 ham               1 
3009527296 cheese            1
```

The SQLite code:

```
sql = ("SELECT Users_Food.Barcode, Users_Food.Item, Recipe1.Ham_Swiss_Omelet FROM Users_Food INNER JOIN Recipe1 ON Users_Food.Barcode = Recipe1.Barcode WHERE Recipe1.Ham_Swiss_Omelet = '1'")
```

It combines the two tables with the Barcode in common and and the corresponding food names and availability. However, If one of the barcode values is not present in the Pre-Loaded table, when I compare how can I go about coding to know that it is not there while still displaying what is there in common between those two tables? It is like checking to see if the tables are identical.

Comment: See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve]. You haven't asked a question, said whether the code is working, or explained what you don't understand. If it's not working, how do you know? Edit the question, these comments are to help you write a better question, not to chat.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that for me. I will do that right now. Thanks for the links. I will edit right away.

Comment: Additionally, please post tables as text rather than images (just format as code for fixed-width layout)

Comment: We appreciate the effort to improve your question, I'm sure you'll get help soon :)

Comment: So, you want a list of ingredients in the recipe and for each ingredient, a flag to indicate whether it's also in the user's list? Try messing around with SQL in the sqlite commandline. Eg. look at `select * from Recipe1 r left join Users_Food u on r.Barcode=u.Barcode`

Comment: Yes exactly. The Barcode must be in the both tables. If at least one barcode is missing, like in the example above, then I would like to print out "not all values exists". Meaning it is exist in the Pre-Loaded table but not in the Users table. I'll try your method now.

Comment: It just produced the same result above in my question except it added two columns for the barcodes.